# DownValue "associative array" to list?

Tags: data-structures, downvalues

I have a "sparse array" like this

```
arr[1.5]=0.4, arr[3.5]=0.7, arr[7]=0.3
```

which is not really a sparse array since the keys are not all integers. This is like a hash table or associative array.

How can I convert `arr` into a list? I tried `Normal[arr]`, but it won't work.
I would like to be able to compute `Total@arr`, but first it needs to be converted to a normal list.

Comment: In fact this is exactly a hash table.

Answer (score 9):

This might be the general sort of operation you seek.

```
keyvalpairs = 
 DownValues[arr] /. Verbatim[HoldPattern][arr[k_]] :> k

(* Out[121]= {1.5 :> 0.4, 3.5 :> 0.7, 7 :> 0.3} *)
```

Comment: I was trying to do exactly that but I couldn't figure out the pattern/replacement I needed +1.

Comment: @sOrce it took me a few tries. That combination of HoldPattern and Verbatim is not something I am accustomed to needing.

Answer (score 8):

Here is one way to do it:

```
{arr[1.5] = 0.4, arr[3.5] = 0.7, arr[7] = 0.3}
Total[DownValues[arr][[All, 2]]]
```